# How to fix TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I'm trying to scrape bits of information with Beautiful Soup, I put a `try` ... `except` in the for loop but it doesn't seem to be efficient. I must do something wrong but I dont know where.

This gets html from a list of URL's called `occupations_list`. Example of a URL: https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1

```
for occupation in occupations_list:
  offers_page = requests.get(occupation)
  offers_soup = BeautifulSoup(offers_page.content, 'lxml')
  offers = offers_soup.find('ul', class_='result-list list-unstyled')
```

This get a headline in the html I got above

```
for job in offers:
    try:
      headline = job.find('h2', class_='t4 media-heading').text
    except Exception as e:
      pass
    print(headline)
```

The problem is that I got the following error message after a few headlines have already been scraped:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-cbf6b87ac0f9> in <module>()
      3   offres_soup = BeautifulSoup(offres_page.content, 'lxml')
      4   offres = offres_soup.find('ul', class_='result-list list-unstyled')
----> 5   for job in offres:
      6     try:
      7       headline = job.find('h2', class_='t4 media-heading').text

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` denotes that nothing was found, you might use `if` ... `is None` check rather than try-except to skip if nothing was found as follows

```
for occupation in occupations_list:
  offers_page = requests.get(occupation)
  offers_soup = BeautifulSoup(offers_page.content, 'lxml')
  offers = offers_soup.find('ul', class_='result-list list-unstyled')
  if offers is None:
    continue
  print("Processing offers")
```

replace `print("Processing offers")` with your actual processing